# Android do in background

Tags: android

```
package com.example.handy;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.R.integer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    private EditText ipaddress;
    private Button connect;
    private Button wipe;
    private static String myIp;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
        ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ipaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipaddress_felid);

        connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        wipe =(Button) findViewById(R.id.wipe);



        //Button press event listener
        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
             {
                 setMyIp(ipaddress.getText().toString());
                // myComs.sending_data(getMyIp() , "Got connected");
                try
                 {

                    InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(getMyIp());
                    Socket s = new Socket(inet, 2000);
                    new Incomingdata(s).execute();
                    OutputStream o = s.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(o);





                     p.println("You are connected");
                     p.flush();

                     readContacts();
                     readSms();




                 }



                 catch (UnknownHostException e) 
                 {
                    ipaddress.setText("Unknown host");
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



             }


         });
        wipe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
             {
                String kill = "5";
                 myComs.sending_data(MainActivity.getMyIp(), kill);
                 finish();

             }
             });
    }
public class Incomingdata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    Socket s ;
    String input;

    public Incomingdata(Socket socket)
    {
        super();
        this.s = socket;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        try
        {   
            InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
            Scanner r = new Scanner(in);
            while(s.isConnected()&& r.hasNext())
            {
                String input =r.nextLine();

            }

        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            ipaddress.setText("Unknown host");
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void input)
    {
        System.out.println(""+input);
    }

}
```

I have no errors and its not crashing buts its not listening to my incoming message coming in and it is not displaying it

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
while(s.isConnected() && r.hasNext()) {
    String input =r.nextLine();
}
```

Your while loop currently only checks to see if you are connected, and has the potential to be an infinite loop. Your Scanner, `r`, on the other hand will not have an infinite amount of data, so repeatedly calling `nextLine()` means you'll eventually run out of data to read, and get the `NoSuchElementException` that you have.

Edit: As codeMagic mentioned in the comments, you should call setText() on the UI thread in onPostExecute() and not in doInBackground() as that will just result in more exceptions once you fix this one.

Comment: Also, not your current issue but you should be calling `setText()` in a different method, say `onPostExecute()` since you can't update `UI` elements in `doInBackground()`

Comment: Right Guys i made all the changes and its running with no errors now but i still dont know how to get the message now